# PHP curl redirect works in one env but not the other

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have a php script that I am testing via eclipse and chrome. Its goal is to return the final url after redirects, given an original url. It's behaving differently in each env: when I test from eclipse (debug as web application), it works and gives the final url. When I run it from chrome (http://myhost/xxxx.php), it doesn't work - gives the original url.

I am guessing this has sth to do with php config, but I am not sure. here is the code, I'd appreciate if someone could comment, or at least has a clue on how to diagnose this...

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    // $info['url'] holds the result url
```

Comment: Might be the difference between running command line and browser, assuming that's what eclipse does.

Comment: I realize that, my q is what could be a difference that causes this, and how to diagnose it? tnx.